# How can i specify theme for scrolled composite using css?

Tags: java, css, swt, rcp

In my rcp application i want to apply theme.I am able to change everything accept the scrollcomposite part.I want to know that whether it is possible to apply theme to scrolled composite or not.

CSS:

```
Label, Button[style~='SWT.CHECK'] {
    font: vrinda 10px;
    color: black;
}

Composite Label {
    color: black;
}

#SeparatorLabel {
    color: #1d659f;
}

Text {
    font: vrinda 10px;
}

Composite Text {
background-color: gradient linear orange black 50% 20%
    color: black;
}

Group Text {
    background-color: gradient linear white black 50% 20%
    color: black;
}
Group Label {
    color: black;
}



TabFolder {
 /* The tab rendering background for the min/max toolbar pulls 
     * background from the tabfolder's background (or it's parent?)
     * and so the gradient doesn't come through. So just set the
     * tabfolder's background to a color */
    /*background-color: white #dddddd #eeeeee 35% 25% 25%;*/
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: white;
    swt-simple: true;   
}


 TabItem {
    color: black;
    font: vrinda 8px;
}

TabItem:selected {
    background-color: #cccccc #e8e8e8 60%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font: vrinda 8px;
}

TabItem.active:selected {
    background-color: #ffffff #cccccc #dddddd 50% 50%;
    color: #1d659f;
    font: bold;
}






Scrolledcomposite Text{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
Scrolledcomposite Label {
    color: black;
}



SashForm {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

Table {
    background-color: #e8e8e8 #cccccc 60%;
    color: black;
    font: vrinda 8px;
}

.MTrimBar {
    background-color: white #dddddd #eeeeee 35% 25% 25%;
    color: white;
    font: vrinda 8px;
}

CTabFolder {
    /* The tab rendering background for the min/max toolbar pulls 
     * background from the tabfolder's background (or it's parent?)
     * and so the gradient doesn't come through. So just set the
     * tabfolder's background to a color */
    /*background-color: white #dddddd #eeeeee 35% 25% 25%;*/
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: white;
    swt-simple: true;   
}


CTabItem {
    color: black;
    font: Verdana 8px;
}

CTabItem:selected {
    background-color: #cccccc #e8e8e8 60%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font: Verdana 8px;
}

CTabItem.active:selected {
    background-color: #ffffff #cccccc #dddddd 50% 50%;
    color: #1d659f;
    font: bold;
}
```

Comment: How is this related with Java at all?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is related because `ScrolledComposite` is a SWT widget and therefore related to Java.

Comment: @Baz if you read the question content, there's nothing to do with Java. OP's application might be written in Java, but AFAICS this is a CSS question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP is asking how to style a Java component with CSS. This *is* specific to Java. If you ask people with expertise just in CSS they won't be able to answer it.

Comment: @Baz so the question is *how to define the CSS for the Java component* or I am mistaken?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Updated my previous content. You have to add the `Java` tag to attract the people able to answer this question.

Comment: He does mention that he is writing an RCP application which uses CSS to influence the appearance of the controls. That is the Connection between CSS & Java in this case.